# Moving files from current directory to one directory below

Tags: unix, cp, mv

I am trying to move 2 files from current directory (/base/level1/level2) to one directory below (/base/level1)

Is there any easier command other than mv file1 /base/level1 ? I'm trying to understand if we have some command that move it to a specific level up or down in the current folder structure.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this one is navigating to the path where I want to move the file and run the following command.

cp ./level2/file1 .

or

cp ./file1 ./level2/file1

Please share other solutions as well

Thanks,
AMK

Answer (score 0):

You could use wildcards if the 2 files have something uniquely in common.

ie. `mv file*.ext path/to/new/dest/`

This will move all files starting with "file" and ending with the extension ".ext" to the destination. [Have a look at this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214560/how-to-move-multiple-files-at-once-to-a-specific-destination-directory) and [this](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/wildcards.php) which will explain wildcards a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `..` for "one directory up".

And you can give more than 2 arguments to `mv`, the last always being the destination.

So `mv file1 file2 ..` would move those 2 files a directory up.

Or `mv * ..` to move all files.